# Android WebView propt URL only once

Tags: android, eclipse, android-webview

I have an app that uses webview. I want the app when first launched to allow you to enter the URL you wish to use and bind it to the app never prompting again unless defaults are cleared through application setting on the OS side.

How can this be done?
I am very new at application building so dummy it up for me with the instructions please!

```
package com.namespace;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;
import android.webkit.CookieManager;
import android.webkit.CookieSyncManager;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MYAPPNAME extends Activity
{
final Activity activity = this;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptCookie(true); 
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient()

    {

        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress)
        {
            activity.setTitle("Loading...");
            activity.setProgress(progress * 100);

            if(progress == 100)
                activity.setTitle(R.string.app_name);

        }
    });

    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description,        String failingUrl)
        {
            // Handle the error
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
        {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    });
    WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();

    settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webView.loadUrl("http://my.app.URL");


}
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using sharedpreferences.  See [this link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref) for examples.